# Test passes on Validation and fails on Deployment

Tags: change-set, unit-test

I'm trying to deploy a change set with one updated class to production.
When I run Deploy it fails because an assertion failure in some other class in my org.
When I run Validation only it passes with no errors and when I run all tests in my production org I get no errors as well.

Any idea why I get the failure only on deployment?

Comment: What causes the deploy to fail? You can click the "View Results" next to the deployed change set to see what goes wrong.

Comment: @PJC3 as I wrote some assertion failure in some other class in my org.

Comment: If you run the existing test class independently (the one that has the assertion failure during deployment), does it still have the same assertion failure? If so, it could be a case where there's a problem with that class which needs fixed and SF is "forcing" you to fix it with this deployment. IAC, you need to explore what the source of the assertion failure is.

Comment: When I run the test independently of the deployment it passes. Only during full deployment it fails.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because when the failing test class was written it was done using the properties of the person that wrote it (probably something off his user record or something he has access to and you don't). Now that you're deploying your code, that class is being tested as you, and you didn't match his test class for whatever reason.

If this is the case, change that test class to use the RunAs method.  Here is some documentation that should help.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm