# Test Class passes in sandbox/production. Fails during deployment

Tags: debugging

Requesting insights into another questions.

I have test class which gives no error/debug log exception when it's ran individually.

But the test class runs during the change set deployment, it fails due to the system.assert failure, which actually passes all the time except the deployment.

What are the areas I can look at to start debugging this issue?

++ Very similar to the issue found here..
[Test passes on Validation and fails on Deployment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11594/test-passes-on-validation-and-fails-on-deployment)

I do already have the runas and also the class fails only during change set deployment.

having hard time making any sense..any guidance/nudge will be appreciated.

Thanks a ton!

Regards,

Comment: code too long to share with us ? This could be a lot of things .. its hard to guess. Some type of configuration changes, unless you're using real data in your test, then you've got a whole different problem.

Comment: Also common: hard-coded ids that only exist in the sandbox. But without the error, there's no way to know. Check the Change Set logs, it'll show you what failed and then you can work back from there.

Comment: @Sdry: unfortnately I can't. All the data/records are being created in the test class itself. But here's the scenario which i'm working on:
--Create test record--Update something on test record--which should trigger an actual class(trigger calling a class) then update a field on the test record...asserting the test record--assert fails hence test class fails--but only in deployment

Comment: You didn't forget triggers or workflows in your change set I hope ?  Like I said, without code .. this is stabbing in the dark.

Comment: @Sdry: I know :'(

Comment: Does your test have API version >= 24 or explicit seeAllData=false? Can you deploy the trigger without test? I know, blasphemy... But I suspect some problem with the trigger that's the root cause of test not passing (if needed write something that gives it 1% coverage... like a blind insert without assertion). Trigger's root cause of fail might be a missing field, anything really. The tests that pass in sandbox - do they run in parallel or sequential mode?

Comment: It's 29.0 and we've set seealldata = true. May be i'll try with commented out assert (I'll be hating myself after this :'( )
Actually the trigger calls the class(this is the best practice as we can control the trigger's execution order) and the test class is updating a record which calls the trigger and that trigger calls the class.

Comment: Why are you using SeeAllData=true if you're creating all the data yourself in the test methods?

Comment: Try disabling parallel test execution in production.  Setup | Develop | Apex Test Execution | Options... and check the box to Disable Parallel Test Execution.  Then try your deploy again.

Comment: @drakored if he is getting errors for PriceBooks that is the only way around it I believe..  Reading through this I don't see his actual errors.